# Excel VBA - Selecting random rows based on multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code set which takes a list of ticket data, and randomly selected three rows based on the username in Col D.

However, with a recent change in our ticketing system, I now need to update it to not select certain tickets.  Specifically, I need only INC and SCTASK tickets to be selected, and not RITM tickets.

I am not quite sure how to add the filter so that tickets with RITM in the ticket number (ticket numbers are in Col A) are not included in this search.

```
Sub DailyTicketAudit()

'Set parameters and variables
    Const sDataSheet As String = "Page 1"
    Const sUserCol As String = "D"
    Const lHeaderRow As Long = 1
    Const lShowRowsPerUser As Long = 3
    Const bSortDataByUser As Boolean = False
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range, rShow As Range
    Dim aData() As Variant, aUserRows() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, lRandIndex As Long, lTotalUnqUsers As Long, lMaxUserRows As Long
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\Users\stefan.bagnato\Desktop\Raw Data Files\Audit Tickets Created")
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sDataSheet)
    Sheets("Page 1").name = "Audit Tickets"

'Work with the data range set by parameters
    With ws.Range(sUserCol & lHeaderRow + 1, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sUserCol).End(xlUp))
        If .Row < lHeaderRow + 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data found in [" & sDataSheet & "]" & Chr(10) & _
                   "Verify column containing users is Column [" & sUserCol & "] or correct sUserCol in code." & Chr(10) & _
                   "Verify header row is Row [" & lHeaderRow & "] or correct lHeaderRow in code." & Chr(10) & _
                   "Once corrections have been made and data is available, try again."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        lTotalUnqUsers = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((" & .Address(external:=True) & "<>"""")/COUNTIF(" & .Address(external:=True) & "," & .Address(external:=True) & "&""""))")
        lMaxUserRows = Evaluate("max(countif(" & .Address(external:=True) & "," & .Address(external:=True) & "))")
        If bSortDataByUser Then .Sort .Cells, xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        Set rData = .Cells
        aData = .Value
        ReDim aUserRows(1 To lTotalUnqUsers, 1 To 3, 1 To lMaxUserRows)
    End With

'Load all available rows into the results array, grouped by the user
    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
        For j = LBound(aUserRows, 1) To UBound(aUserRows, 1)
            If IsEmpty(aUserRows(j, 1, 1)) Or aUserRows(j, 1, 1) = aData(i, 1) Then
                If IsEmpty(aUserRows(j, 1, 1)) Then aUserRows(j, 1, 1) = aData(i, 1)
                k = aUserRows(j, 2, 1) + 1
                aUserRows(j, 2, 1) = k
                aUserRows(j, 3, k) = i + lHeaderRow
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

'Select random rows up to lShowRowsPerUser for each user from the grouped results array
    For j = LBound(aUserRows, 1) To UBound(aUserRows, 1)
        Do
            Randomize
            lRandIndex = Int(Rnd() * aUserRows(j, 2, 1)) + 1
            If Not rShow Is Nothing Then
                Set rShow = Union(rShow, ws.Cells(aUserRows(j, 3, lRandIndex), sUserCol))
            Else
                Set rShow = ws.Cells(aUserRows(j, 3, lRandIndex), sUserCol)
            End If
        Loop While rShow.Cells.Count < j * Application.Min(lShowRowsPerUser, aUserRows(j, 2, 1))
    Next j
    rData.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    rShow.EntireRow.Hidden = False

'Format table
    'Sort by Opened By
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Audit Tickets").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        With Worksheets("Audit Tickets").Sort
            .SetRange Range("A2:G" & LastRow)
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
    'Widen columns
        Range("A:B,G:G").ColumnWidth = 15
        Columns("C:D").ColumnWidth = 18
        Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 50
        Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 22
    'Wrap text
        Range("E1:E" & LastRow).WrapText = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Far more efficient, assuming  `aData` holds all the data and the first column is tickets, is to simply process only the two of interest with the following.

Change `1` in `aData(i, 1)` to whichever column holds the items of interest in the array.

```
For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
    If aData(i, 1) = "INC" Or aData(i, 1) = "SCTASK" Then   
        For j = LBound(aUserRows, 1) To UBound(aUserRows, 1)
   ''other code
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Looks like it will work.  I have to get it to search including a wildcard.  The ticket is in the form of INC######, or SCTASK######, so it doesn't do anything without the wildcard.   With your updated code, it seems to break the next section of code (`Select random rows up to lShowRowsPerUser for each user from the grouped results array`), but I don't know that it is because of an issue with the code you provided.  Still trying to figure it out

Comment: Use Like operator maybe

Comment: If aData(i, 1) Like "INC*" Or aData(i, 1) Like "SCTASK*" Then

Comment: You might want to check if has left you with an array that has empty values in it and that is messing with things...

Comment: Hm, does not want to cooperate.  I put a break before the error so I can fix the filter issue first.  I updated the line to `If aData(i, 1) Like "INC" Or aData(i, 1) Like "SCTASK" Then`, but I am still getting unwanted tickets (RITM).  Hmmm

Comment: No luck.  Although, wouldn't we still want that in there so it can correctly calculate the total number of rows?  Or am I misunderstanding the use

Comment: I guess you would need to COUNTIFS <> "RITM" etc to ensure correctly sized array?

Answer (score 0):

You could use advanced filter:

```
    Sheets("Emps").Range("A1:D8").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Emps").Range("F5:F6"), CopyToRange:=Range("A1:B1"), _
    Unique:=False
```

Data to selectively copy:
[image]

Data copied:
[image]

Reference this *short YouTube video*; You can **record a marco to help** yourself **with the code** also:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGUKjXmEi2E

A more **thorough tutorial** is found here:
http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html

This tutorial shows how to get the **source data from outside Excel**:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4189-excel-dynamic-filter-to-new-sheet.html

This tutorial shows how to **split data values based on a column to different sheets** (Fruit column; Apple sheet, Pear sheet, etc.):
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2884-excel-save-filtered-data-new-sheet-workbook.html